# What is the best way to setup a development & production environment for a PHP/MySQL app?

Tags: deployment, version-control, hosting, git-svn

I've been developing a web app locally on my local MAMP computer for the last few months. Now I am ready to launch it while continuing to add enhancements/fixes. So, I am wondering what is a good way to implement a development AND production server in order to efficiently manage updates, prevent overwrites, and seamlessly add other developers into the workflow. I also want something that has a minimal learning curve for me. Personally, for whatever reason, I've never been able to fully grasp version control systems like Git or SVN so I am hoping for an easier solution until I am able to invest more info the business.

As I see it, the options that I have are:

- Spend more time learning Git before launching. And hoping that I don't break anything while further developing my app.
- Buy two hosting accounts. One for Dev and one for Prod, where only I can do the deployments into Prod. I suppose I'd have to keep track of all files we've modified in a spreadsheet that are deemed ready for deployment.
- Editing right on the FTP (no Dev server).

Are there any other options that you can recommend? I've heard that there are some new types of Web Hosting companies that can do the heavy lifting...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While personally, I have had good experiences using svn/git for multi-developer websites, I can understand your reticence to start relying on something you are not entirely familiar with. Unfortunately, I do believe that is your best option, but failing that, you might try using subdomains. My former employer would create test area on the disk and point *beta.thedomainname.com* at it. When bug fixes or upgrades were complete and verified to be working in the beta directory, the entire directory would be copied over to the live domain. Not the most elegant solution, but it worked. It certainly is cheaper than buying two hosting accounts.

Comment: It is important to note, though, that this method does not provide any sort of backup. You will need to remember or set up automated backups to make sure you do not lose data.

Comment: Thanks, cscott. Very helpful. In terms of the subdomain solution, I am wondering how did you deal with developers working on the files while you are moving the whole directory. For example, I am still in the process of coding a bug fix and you move the whole directory over to Production, you can potentially copy over files in the middle of my development. Basically with missing code. Did you mandate that all developers must log off and close all files just prior to the migration?

Comment: Essentially, yes. We had weekly meetings. Every Friday, we went through and checked where everything was. If beta was in a stable state, then we scheduled an update to run at midnight. If there was something that needed to be fixed immediately, it was the responsibility of the developer(s) working on the bug fix to contact everyone before the migration. As I said, it is not the most elegant solution, but it is functional and easy to understand.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am going to try your solution while learning Git. :-)